# Extract latest version from xml file using shell script

Tags: xml, bash, shell, maven

I am trying to get the latest artifact number from my repository,
I can't use the `<release>3.4.6.17</release>` tag because I want to control the version which I'm taking the latest version from.

For example in this **maven-metadata.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.company.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <release>3.4.6.17</release>
    <versions>
      <version>3.3.0.89</version>
      <version>3.3.17.65</version>
      <version>3.3.17.66</version>
      <version>3.3.19.65</version>
      <version>3.4.2.70</version>
      <version>3.4.2.71</version>
      <version>3.4.4.39</version>
      <version>3.4.4.40</version>
      <version>3.4.4.41</version>
      <version>3.4.4.42</version>
      <version>3.4.6.1</version>
      <version>3.4.6.2</version>
      <version>3.4.6.3</version>
      <version>3.4.6.4</version>
      <version>3.4.6.16</version>
      <version>3.4.6.17</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20201011113748</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

I want to get the latest of the `3.4.4` versions, which is: `3.4.4.42`.

And not the latest uploaded artifact which is: `3.4.6.17`.

Is there a way in a shell script to parse that file by a given version (version=3.3.4)?

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do it.  What have you tried, and why didn't it work?  In general, parsing XML without an XML parser is a hard work and/or unreliable, but if the format is as shown, it can be done.

Comment: I upvoted this question for the simple reason that the OP did not make any assumption that this had to be done with `sed` or `awk`. The OP asked the correct question. While I generally agree with @JonathanLeffler, for XML manipulation in a shell I like to make an exception as there are more _wrong_ answered out there then right.

Comment: Just as a warning: In most cases it is better to use Maven to resolve the latest version, or alternatively, the REST api or your Nexus or Artifactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### grep

If this xml file is always so flat, you could use `grep` with PCRE to match the text inside the version node, and then do version sorting `-V` with GNU `sort` and get the newer version for your input pattern:

```sh
grep -oP '(?<=<version>)3\.4\.4.*?(?=</version>)' file.xml | sort -V | tail -1
3.4.4.42
```

---

### xmlstarlet

Usually you can find many tools in a shell that can parse xml files and select any part of them, like `xmllint`, `xpath`, `xmlstarlet` etc. They don't parse just text and this is the right and safer approach. Here is an example:

```sh
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//version[starts-with(., "3.4.4")]' -v . -n file.xml
3.4.4.39
3.4.4.40
3.4.4.41
3.4.4.42
```

and again you can pipe the above to `sort -V`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat test.xml | grep -E "<version>3\.4\.4.*</version>" | sort | tail -n 1 | sed 's/<.*>\(.*\)<\/.*>/\1/g' | tr -d [:blank:]
```

1. list the contents of the xml file
2. search for versions beginning with `3.3.4 ...`
3. sort the results
4. keep only the last element (latest version)
5. remove the xml tags with sed
6. remove the whitespace characters like tab or space

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- OP does not have access to a XML parser
- the input file is formatted as displayed in the question
- versions are ordered oldest (earlier in file) to newest (later in file) so as we find matches we just need to keep the latest match

One `awk` solution:

```
$ baseversion='3.4.4'
$ awk -F'[><]' -v bv="^${baseversion}" '             # use ">" and "<" as input field delimiters; build search pattern "^{baseversion}" and pass in as variable "bv"
$2=="version" && $3 ~ bv { latestversion=$3 }        # if field2 equals the string "version" and field3 starts with our "^baseversion" pattern then save field3 in "latestversion"
END                      { print latestversion }     # print the latest version
' maven*xml
3.4.4.42
```

Single line with comments removed:

```
$ awk -F'[><]' -v bv="^${baseversion}" '$2=="version" && $3 ~ bv { latestversion=$3 } END { print latestversion }' maven*xml
3.4.4.42
```